# Can't Convert Alamofire 3 to Alamofire 4, with some error messages

Tags: swift3, alamofire, alamofireimage

I'm trying convert my upload image program. but in stagnating with happened several issue.

I want any advices this issue. 

bellow is previously code with Alamofire 3.

```
    Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        "https://uploadURL",
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData!, name: "image", fileName: nowString + "To" + receiverString! + ".jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, name: key)
            }
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
                    debugPrint(response)
                })

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
```

bellow is current code that writing for Alamofire 4.0.1 and swift 3.(incomplete)

```
    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(data: imageData!, name: "image", fileName: nowString + "To" + receiverString! + ".jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(data: value!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, name: key)
            }
        },to:"https://uploadURL",
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
                    debugPrint(response)
                })

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
```

---

around "multipartFormData" generate thees error message.

> Overloads for 'append' exist with these partially matching parameter
>   lists: (Data, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String),
>   (URL, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)
>
> Cast 'Any' to 'AnyObject' or use 'as!' to force downcast to a more
>   specific type to access members

I'm looking for solution for this issue...

Answer (score 0):

The append method signature changed a bit. You're using the following:

```
append(data:name:fileName:mimeType:)
```

They renamed the `name` argument to `withName` to be compliant with Swift 3 API design guidelines. So you should use:

```
append(_:withName:fileName:mimeType:)
```

Modify your code as shown below and it should all work.

```
Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "image", fileName: nowString + "To" + receiverString! + ".jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(data: value!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, name: key)
        }
    },to:"https://uploadURL",
      encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
                debugPrint(response)
            })

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

Note: the only thing I changed is the `name` argument so it's `withName` instead. And I removed the `data` label.

Comment: thank you for your advice. after changed above, still receive this error message -> Argument labels '(data:, withName:, fileName:, mimeType:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: I overlooked a detail, they changed the data argument as well. You shouldn't explicitly name it in your call anymore. I updated the corrected code for you.

Comment: thank you for your coding ! fixed error about Argument labels :) but,still not fixed this error ->" Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Any'" around "multipartFormData.append(data: value!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, name: key)"